# How to serve bytes or images to Blazor-Maui App?

Tags: maui-blazor

How would I go about creating a small server for use internally by a Blazor-Maui Desktop app?

I'm trying to serve images that are created on the fly into an `img` tag:

```html
<img src="/img-generator-service?data=576587" />
```

I'd like my Blazor-Maui app to instantiate a service that works as a webserver serving bytes to localhost, something like:

```cs
public async Task<byte[]> ImgGeneratorService(string data);
```

Or in the asp.net core pattern:

```cs
[HttpGet("img-generator-service")
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string data);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. From your image service, http://img-generator-service?data=576587, assuming 576587 is the image id and file format is jpeg, read the corresponding image from disk or memory as a byte array. Then convert it into base64 string, i.e, from binary to text using Convert.ToBase64String() and return the string.
2. From your app, if it is embedding a browser control, you can pass the data to `<img>` tag as a string like below,

```
<img src="@image">
```

```
@code {
    protected string image;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        string bytes = GetImageFromService(576587);//Service returns string
        image = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works for images and small files, but large files can be too big for Base64 encoding.